# Insert Data from one mysql table to another ( Notice: Array to string conversion )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get data `htmlCode` from a table `tickets` in my Database and then trying to insert it in another table `users`

here is the flowing code that i wrote and it gives me a error Notice: Array to string conversion

I have a little bit of idea about my stupidity that i am trying to insert Array into database which should be a string , so is there any easier way transfer data from one table to another or any correction of my flowing code ?

```
<?php
        try{
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "dbuser", "mypass");
            }
            catch(PDOException $pe)
                {
                    die('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
                }

                $sql = "SELECT `htmlCode` FROM `tickets`";
                $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

                if(!$stmt)
                {
                    die("Execute query error, because: ". $conn->errorInfo());
                }

                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                // print_r ($row); //prints an array 


                 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (row) VALUES (:tickets)";
                 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                 $stmt->bindParam(':tickets' , $row);
                 $stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Your `users` table really has a column named `row`? I have a feeling there's lots more wrong with your script than what we've identified in the answers.

Comment: no ....  users table has also a column named tickets ... first i have tried to get the data from `tickets` table and then try to insert it into users table where there is also a column called tickets

Comment: Why did you write `(row)` if you meant `(tickets)`? You understand that `INSERT` is for creating _new_ rows, not updating existing rows, don't you?

Comment: oh .. i have mismatched the (row) with (tickets) first it should be   INSERT INTO users (tickets) VALUES (:row) .. thank you very much ... and using `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` solves the whole problem :)

Comment: You can use a JOIN in UPDATE to copy data directly as well, rather than two queries.

Comment: Thx for the ans but .. never used a `JOIN` so what it would be for my two queries ??

Comment: The general structure is `UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.x = t2.y SET t1.col1 = t2.col2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a single query:

```
INSERT INTO users (row)
SELECT htmlCode FROM tickets
LIMIT 1 /* since your original script doesn't loop, it only copies one row */
```

`$conn->errorInfo()` returns an array, not a string, so you can't print it directly. Try:

```
die("Execute query error, because: ". implode(' ', $conn->errorInfo()));
```

Comment: it gives Execute query error, because: Array ... what now ?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to display the error correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching an associative array to the database. You just need to get the right value from that array, and bind it:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':tickets' , $row['htmlCode']);
```

Answer (score 0):

`bindParam` expects the second argument to be a string, but `$row` is an array.  You even use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, which means "associative array."

Fairly simple to fix, though:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':tickets' , $row['htmlCode']);
```

Comment: thats removes the error but doesnt insert the data .....

Answer (score 0):

fetch_assoc() returns an associative array in PHP, which is why you get an array.

The solution is to do this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':tickets' , $row['htmlCode']);
```